# List field input in django rest frameowrk browsable api - mongoengine

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, mongoengine, browsable

I have created a `serializer` that takes a list argument `tags`, but on the `django-rest-framework` browsable api, It doesn't seem to work.

Code:

**Model**

```py
class SocialFeed(Document):
    platform = StringField(max_length=20, required=True, choices=('facebook', 'twitter', 'instagram'))
    tags = ListField(default=None)
    created_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(), required=True)
```

**Serializer**

```py
class SocialFeedCreateSerializer(DocumentSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SocialFeed
        fields = [
            'id',
            'platform',
            'tags'
        ]
```

**View**

```py
class SocialFeedCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = SocialFeed.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SocialFeedCreateSerializer
```

But on the browsable `API`, It shows a simple input box to enter tags, and I don't know what format should I put the tags in on the browsable `API` side, and I am not receiving list of tags instead a string.

I have tried following inputs:

```
#1 - ['social media', 'digital media', 'digital']
#2 - 'social media', 'digital media', 'digital'
#3 -  social media, digital media, digital
#4 - "social media", "digital media", "digital"
```

But on the `MongoDb`, when I fetch the document, It shows string instead a list of tags, like this:

```py
"tags" : [
    "['social media','digital media','digital']"
]

"tags" : [
    "'social media','digital media','digital'"
]

"tags" : [
    "social media, digital media, digital]"
]

"tags" : [
    "\"social media\", \"digital media\", \"digital\""
]
```

**Required Output**

```py
"tags" : [
    "social media",
    "digital media",
    'digital"
]
```

If anybody has faced the same issue, please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DRF does only support Django's fields. You likely need to make some fields more explicits in the serializer's declaration, like making `tags` inherit from a `serializer.ListField`.

Comment: I tried to include field imported using `from mongoengine.fields import ListField` and in the serializer declaration, It looks like this `tags = ListField()`, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: It's not going to work if you're mixin DRF fields with Mongoenging one.

Comment: Can you please guide me how should I accomplish this or any reference for situation like this?